# How to avoid re-verifying app store?

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

My iPhone says “since this is the first time you ...” when it ISN'T.  And then it asks security questions which are NOT the ones I set.  Did the same thing last time I tried to download a non-free item, and I had to call Apple and spend ten minutes proving my identity through an e-mail exchange.  And that won’t work right now, because I can only get that e-mail on an iPad that just died.

How can I get around this, and more importantly, make it stop happening?

Answer (score 1):

Log in to your email somewhere else, then contact Apple.

Comment: If you find it interesting enough to answer someones question it is common decency to give them a point for asking the question :)

Comment: @Buscar웃 I'd say refraining from down voting this on lack of research is a +1 in my book. We would rather have an answer than a vote in most cases, so although I see your point in many cases - it's not a hard and fast rule by any stretch.

Comment: @bmike I would highly recommend to NOT discourage new comers instantly with a negative vote. I would give them a chance till about 3 or more questions. At that stage they got hocked up and see they points rising, and they will actually feel the impact of points reduction. Having one point and negative vote nothing happens.

Comment: OK, that sort of answers half the question, i.e., I get around it with the same proctalgia as the first time.  But I’m really more interested in the other part: how to make this malfunction stop.

Comment: Talk to Apple about that.

Comment: That’s what I had to do the first time.  Call Apple and go through a Rube Goldberg operation that only fixed it for that single purchase.